# Spark standalone not working

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting an error in spark standalone. Whenever I am trying to start

```
./start-master.sh
```

I am getting below error -

> ```
>  spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: line 93: [: too many arguments
> ```

I have tried to debug spark-class file as well. Code is getting error at this line of `spark-class.sh` :

```
if [ $LAUNCHER_EXIT_CODE != 0 ]; then
  exit $LAUNCHER_EXIT_CODE
fi
```

^Could be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was a bug and got fixed with versions >2.0.0

I was able to reproduce this issue and updating to an earlier version solved this.

More information on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16586

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually run the master and worker as follow :

1-Go to C:\spark\bin folder

2-Run spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master  (it will give you a URL with this form spark://ip:port)

3-Run spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://ip:port

4-Run spark-shell --master spark://ip:port to connect an application to the newly created cluster.